# How to redirect to other Component with passing some data

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have two components

- FilterCandidate
- ListAllCandidate

ListAllCandidate fetches the List of all candidates(paginated) from    server and render them.

FilterCandidate gets the filter Criteria from user such as age and call the api to fetch the candidates according to criteria.

Now how can i call ListAllCandidate with the Data fetched in FilterCandidate?Do i require redux here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use external state management library, it will require that `ListAllCandidate` and `FilterCandidate` have a common ancestor. This common ancestor will (possibly) handle data fetching, keep it in state and pass down to children as props.

Read more about [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).